# perl get info from database with selectrow_array

Tags: perl

I am working under perl. I am implementing a dynamic query and I have problems with this stuff , If you could give me a piece of advice during my searching.

Now, my static query:

```
 my $envoi_numfact = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT envoi_numfact FROM user.envoi where envoi_reference='hapiness'");

 print Dumper($envoi_numfact);
```

I have a nice result :

```
$VAR1 = '1611029546';
```

So I would like to transform it in dynamic query such as :

```
my $envoi_numfact = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT envoi_numfact FROM user.envoi where envoi_reference=?",undef,$hash_infos{ope_ref}    );
```

Where `$hash_infos{ope_ref}` represents `envoi_reference`.

As a result, I have :

```
$VAR1 = undef;
```

Anyone couls help me ?

Comment: What's in `$hash_infos{ope_ref}`?

Comment: Your query is correct and your Perl syntax is correct. If there are no results, that's because the query does not return any. That probably means the data inside your `$hash_infos{ope_ref}` variable does not correspond to a row in your database.

Comment: `selectrow_array` returns an array, not an array reference. So write `my @envoi_numfact=...` or `my ($envoy_numfact)=...`.

Comment: @PerlDuck in scalar context, `selectrow_array` returns a single element of the array (in that case, since only `envoi_numfact` is fetched, it returns it). However the documentation of DBI discourages using `selectrow_array` in scalar context.

Comment: @Dada Yes, you are right. They discourage it especially when it returns `undef`, like in the above case.

Comment: @PerlDuck, or more precisely, it says that `selectrow_array` shouldn't be used because it may return either the first or last field. In this case, those are the same thing, so there's no problem.

Answer (score -4):

I am a winner ! I have just forgotten the closing bracket.

```
my $envoi_numfact = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT envoi_numfact FROM user.envoi where envoi_reference=?",undef,$hash_infos{ope_ref}    );
```

becomes

```
        my $envoi_numfact = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT envoi_numfact FROM user.envoi where envoi_reference = ?",undef,($hash_infos{ope_ref}));
```

Comment: No. What did you change? You just put parenthesis around the `$hash_infos{ope_ref}`? That's a list constructor that gets flattened out by Perl. It doesn't matter if those are there or not. You could wrap ten pairs of parens around it and nothing would change. It has to be something else you did. Probably you changed the values inside your hash. I'm happy for you that you got it to work, but those parens are not what fixed it. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the different answers !

Comment: `($hash_infos{ope_ref})` is identical to `$hash_infos{ope_ref}` in that situation, just like `(2)+2` is identical to `2+2`.